# Klov 0.1.1 doesn't display info "Tests Executed Today"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports

Using the klov-0.1.1 to display the tests information, some information isnt displayed.

When the test runner finish (nunit3-console), is possible to see logs, test pass info, test fail info, but the info "Tests Executed Today" and "Total Tests" keep with the count zero.

Have something to configure in my solution? Below one report example:

[image]

Comment: Support for Klov with .NET was never fully implemented and as far as I know, support is dropped starting version 4.0.  I would not suggest using Klov as the code is not open-source making it impossible to maintain the repo for version 3 and lower for both Java and .NET.  With Java version 4.0, Klov is fully supported and that is what I would recommend but unfortunately it is not possible in your case..

Comment: You are right @foursyth. I saw the newest version of klov for Java. But my project is fully created in .NET and its hard to migrate to other language. 
I'll survive with this version, when the upgrade for .Net is done (klov 4) let's upgrade the project. Thanks for reply!!